# How do I go about writing this grading system?

Tags: java, if-statement, system, statements

None of the other answers gave me any indication of what to do in my predicament so I thought I'd start a new question.

I want to write a program where someone inputs their number of As, Bs, and Cs and then it outputs their mark.

These are the minimum requirements:

```
EA: 12 As, 2 Bs   
HA: 6 As, 6 Bs, 2 Cs
CA: 8 Bs, 5 Cs
SA: 12 Cs
PA: 6 Cs
```

I've tried a couple of ways but none work or I either foresee that the code will be very long and overly complicated.

One major hurdle I had was that my criteria would often class it as two grades.

For example:

```
//EA Grade

if (numA >= 11 && numB >=1)
{ grade = "EA"; }

//HA Grade

if (numA >=5 && numB >=5)
{ grade = "HA"; }
```

---

The problem there is that if the number of As and Bs qualify them for an EA, they'll also qualify for a HA. This is obviously not desirable. How would I go about fixing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem there is that if the number of As and Bs qualify them for an EA, they'll also qualify for a HA. This is obviously not desirable. How would I go about fixing this problem?

The answer to that specific part of the question is: Use `else`:

```
if (numA >= 11 && numB >=1) {
    grade = "EA";
} else if (numA >=5 && numB >=5) {
//^^^^------------------------------ here
    grade = "HA";
}
// ...and so on...
```

Another approach is to have objects with the requirements for each of the levels, in an array, sorted by the "best" grade (EA, if I'm understanding you correctly), and then have a loop through those objects checking to see which grade the person qualified for and taking the first one. Which is more appropriate to what you're doing is up to you, both have pros and cons in terms of maintainability and clarity.

Comment: The problem there is that it'll assume everything that isn't an EA is a HA, which is not necessarily true.

Comment: @user3414510: No, you keep the series going: `if (...) else if (...) else if (...)`

Comment: Oh, I see. So if the first statement turns to be true, the second one (the 'else') won't run?

Comment: I've ran into another problem. I got the program to run but it has some issues.

If I enter '11 As', '1 B' & '2 Cs', it returns a 'HA'.

This is because I wrote:
else if (numB >= 5 && numC <= 3)
{ grade = "HA"; }

Now it shouldn't return a HA but I don't know how to do it any other way because if I add that "num B >= 5", that wouldn't account for situations where someone might get 11 As & 3 Bs or something similar, which would technically be a HA. How would I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I have just given a try to the program have a look

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*EA: 12 As, 2 Bs   
*HA: 6 As, 6 Bs, 2 Cs
*CA: 8 Bs, 5 Cs
*SA: 12 Cs
*PA: 6 Cs*/
public class cases {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of A's B's C's to declare your grades");
        int a=in.nextInt();
        int b=in.nextInt();
        int c=in.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the choice to know the Result 1:EA 2:HA 3:CA  4:SA  5:PA");
       int choice=in.nextInt();
       switch(choice)
       {
       case 1:  if(a>=11&&b>=1){
                   System.out.println("You are EA Grade Holder");

                 }
                    else
                         System.out.println("You have to find out with other choices");
                  break;

       case 2:   if(a>=5&&b>=5&&c>=1){

                     System.out.println("You are HA Grade Holder");

                   }
                  else
                     System.out.println("You have to find out with other choices");
                      break;
       case 3:       if(a>=7&&b>=7){

                     System.out.println("You are CA Grade Holder");

                 }
                    else
                     System.out.println("You have to find out with other choices");
                    break;
       case 4:   if(c>=12){

                          System.out.println("You are SA Grade Holder");

                       }
                 else
                      System.out.println("You have to find out with other choices");
                 break;
       case 5:   if(c==6){

                     System.out.println("You are PA Grade Holder");

                  }
                else
                   System.out.println("You have to find out with other choices");
                break;

       default:System.out.println("you have not entered proper choice");


       }


    }
}
```

Comment: While that may work sometimes, but it wouldn't account for a situation where someone gets 11 As & 3 Bs, which should be a HA but the program wouldn't return that.

Comment: @user3414510 Ill come soon with an update ill try to device some logic lets see :)

Comment: Never mind, I found a solution (I think).

I changed the HA statement to:

else if (numA >= 5 && numC= 0)
{ grade = "HA"; }

This returns the right grade, assuming the person puts their grade in correctly. Thanks for your help. :)